# Describe API purpose

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc

I use `eclipse`.Normally we can use `javadoc.exe` to create `HTML Doc` in about packages, classes, methods, fields and ... that are in project.But how I can create a doc to describe purpose of whole of the API and add it to usual java docs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create an overview.html file, and pass its location to javadoc using the `-overview` option, as described in [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/javadoc.html#CHDGDJAH).

Comment: The documentation does not describe how to use that -overview option. I tried -overview "src/overview.html" but it had no effect.